# How to Search Github Issues w/Label that Contains Sub-String

Tags: github

I already searched SO, but please tell me if this is a dup and please point me in the direction if so.

In GitHub issues search, can I do something similar to this, `is:open label-contains:meeting` or `is:open meeting in:label` in search box for repo issues?

Desired result would be all issues that are open and have labels that contain the sub-string "meeting".  So, results would, for example, contain issues with the following labels:

- `team-meeting`
- `a-meeting-of-minds`
- `meeting`
- `meetings`

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/

Comment: Thx, @jonrsharpe Sorry if I'm being dense here, but that's a page I looked at already, to no avail.  I did a re-check just now, but I still don't see where labels can be fuzzy searched.  ;-)

Comment: Then I guess they can't!